# How to set up/use fakechroot along fakeroot using only busybox commands?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, openwrt, arm, ubuntu-18.04

## Situation

I was given an outdated system without root access. So when I try to load any dynamically linked executable, I’m getting a message stating a specific `GLIBC_VERSION_` symbol wasn’t found (the installed Glibc version date from 2011).

Busybox is pretty much the only program being installed (there are also third party tools but I didn’t got the complete list).
Neverless, as I’m having more 24Gb of free ext4 space in my `~` I downloaded and extracted an Ubuntu tar root into my `$HOME` with libfakechroot installed from the `rootfs.tar`.

Normally, you start fakeroot and fakechroot through their commands, but in that case, attempting to run any third party programs leads undefined GLIBC symbols.

## Question

In that situation, which shell commands I need to use for at least launching `apt-get` successfully ?

I guess they is some setting `LD_PRELOAD` and calling `$HOME/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` since `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` is statically linked, but what would be the full shell script ?

Comment: Of course, Fakechroot and fakeroot aren’t installed on the main rootfs. They are only present in the one I extracted into my `$HOME` folder.